# Mule Batch Job StepResults are Miselading

Tags: mule, batch-processing, dataweave, mulesoft

I was working with sample batchJob and figured something about the BatchStepResults. Created a simple application with small payload and BatchJob, with 3 BatchSteps .

I have below payload and as per the batchJob the batchstep1 should process 4 records and Batchstep2 should be 3 and batchstep3 should be 1. But why it always 4 for each step ?

```
[
    {
        "value": "true"
    },
    {
        "value": "false"
    },
    {
        "value": "true"
    },
    {
        "value": "true"
    }
]
```

And below is the flow :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd">
    <flow name="sampleFlow" doc:id="20a1422c-6cde-484c-855d-78910bdbf8d3" >
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="983b6e46-0dab-4ca5-b4e0-82db0cda7b4e" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="5" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <set-payload value='#[[
    {
        "value": "true"
    },
    {
        "value": "false"
    },
    {
        "value": "true"
    },
    {
        "value": "true"
    }
]]' doc:name="Set Payload" doc:id="d1157ac5-196e-4bbc-a4e8-1dea053c6d66" />
        <batch:job jobName="sampleBatch_Job" doc:id="4437b942-4e2f-485e-8b9b-009873b44684" >
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step_1" doc:id="28651eb8-710d-46ef-8868-d98fbc8e19f2" acceptPolicy="ALL">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="a3001490-d798-4efc-a767-01120c63162e" message="Batch Step 1"/>
                </batch:step>
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step_2" doc:id="075515ed-765b-482b-b08e-aa243014ba74" acceptPolicy="ALL" acceptExpression='#[payload.value == "true"]'>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="977f4aa1-eb99-40a2-85a5-d709fd7757a1" message="Batch Step 2"/>
                </batch:step>
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step_3" doc:id="28934a79-804e-44db-8c8f-63b58a8211ee" acceptExpression='#[payload.value == "false"]' acceptPolicy="ALL">
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="56442f2c-767c-427b-846a-23853c721c04" message="Batch Step 3"/>
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
            <batch:on-complete >
                <scatter-gather doc:name="All" doc:id="1a2c8651-0d8a-4d2c-80d1-8d7e10d1dfd8" >
                    <route >
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Migration process has finished!" doc:id="ad76f37a-0bc4-4532-96bb-b2ba7a2e69cf" message="Migration process has finished!" />
                    </route>
                    <route >
                        <ee:transform doc:name="Prepare migration result email" doc:id="329eadd6-f103-4dce-bf23-947aa04c087d" >
                            <ee:message >
                                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
 output application/json
 ---

payload.stepResults
 ]]></ee:set-payload>
                            </ee:message>
                        </ee:transform>
                        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="ee32daa3-2e5f-4d16-bfdf-b6933fdbc751" message="#[payload]"/>
                    </route>
                </scatter-gather>
            </batch:on-complete>
        </batch:job>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

And If you see the console :

```
 {
  "Batch_Step_1": {
    "failedRecords": 0,
    "successfulRecords": 4,
    "exceptionSummary": {
      "exceptionsCount": {
        
      }
    },
    "receivedRecords": 4
  },
  "Batch_Step_3": {
    "failedRecords": 0,
    "successfulRecords": 4,
    "exceptionSummary": {
      "exceptionsCount": {
        
      }
    },
    "receivedRecords": 4
  },
  "Batch_Step_2": {
    "failedRecords": 0,
    "successfulRecords": 4,
    "exceptionSummary": {
      "exceptionsCount": {
        
      }
    },
    "receivedRecords": 4
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the Mule version?

Comment: @aled version 4.2.0